# Powershell Try Catch IOException DirectoryExist

Tags: powershell

I'm using a power shell script to copy some files from my computer to a USB drive. However, even though I'm catching the System.IO exception, I still get the error at the bottom. How do I properly catch this exception, so it shows the message in my Catch block.

```
CLS

$parentDirectory="C:\Users\someUser"
$userDirectory="someUserDirectory"
$copyDrive="E:"
$folderName="Downloads"
$date = Get-Date
$dateDay=$date.Day
$dateMonth=$date.Month
$dateYear=$date.Year
$folderDate=$dateDay.ToString()+"-"+$dateMonth.ToString()+"-"+$dateYear.ToString();


Try{
     New-Item -Path $copyDrive\$folderDate -ItemType directory
     Copy-Item $parentDirectory\$userDirectory\$folderName\* $copyDrive\$folderDate
   }
Catch [System.IO]
{
    WriteOutput "Directory Exists Already"
}


New-Item : Item with specified name E:\16-12-2014 already exists.
At C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\checkexist.ps1:15 char:9
+         New-Item -Path $copyDrive\$folderDate -ItemType directory
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (E:\16-12-2014:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suggest actually catching the error in this case. Although that may be the correct action in general, in this specific case I would do the following:

```
$newFolder = "$copyDrive\$folderDate"

if (-not (Test-Path $newFolder)) {
    New-Item -Path $newFolder -ItemType directory
    Copy-Item $parentDirectory\$userDirectory\$folderName\* $newFolder
} else {
    Write-Output "Directory Exists Already"
}
```

Comment: This is not atomic! It could be that the folder is created in between the test-path and the creation.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to catch an exception for a `New-Item` call, you need to do two things:

1. Set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` by default its value is `Continue`. This will make the script Stop in case of exceptions.
2. Trap the correct exception and/or all of them

if you want to trap all exceptions, just use `catch` without arguments:

```
catch 
{
    Write-Output "Directory Exists Already"
}
```

if you want to trap a specific exception, first find out which one it is, by checking the value of

```
$error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName
```

and in your case the value is:

```
System.IO.IOException
```

then you can use this value as an argument to your catch, like this:

```
catch [System.IO.IOException]
{
    Write-Output "Directory Exists Already"
}
```

Source worth reading: [An introduction to Error Handling in Powershell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can spot exactly Directory Exist (unfortunally no File Exist error type for files).

```
$resExistErr=[System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ResourceExists

try {
        New-Item item -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch [System.IO.IOException] 
    {
        if ($_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq $resExistErr) {Write-host "Dir Exist"}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the line creating the directory you can catch `[System.IO.IOException]`(not [System.IO]). You should also catch *all* other exceptions that can potentially occur:

```
try {
   New-Item -Path $copyDrive\$folderDate -ItemType directory -ErrorAction Stop
   Copy-Item $parentDirectory\$userDirectory\$folderName\* $copyDrive\$folderDate -ErrorAction Stop
}

catch [System.IO.IOException] {
   WriteOutput $_.Exception.Message
}

catch {
   #some other error
}
```